# Cursor does not include the first select statement in the results

Tags: sql, cursor

I have the following code.I was expecting to see threee tables,for eaach select statement,but for some reason the table for the first select statement is not included in the results.

```
declare @Charge dec(10,2)
DECLARE CRS CURSOR
FOR 

SELECT 0.01*v9.charge  AS firstTENDAYS
from v9
where datepart(day,v9.trans_time_date) between 0 and 10  and 
@Charge=v9.charge


SELECT 0.02*V9.charge  AS secondTENDAYS
 from v9
where datepart(day,v9.trans_time_date) between 11 and 20  and
@Charge=v9.Charge

SELECT 0.03*V9.charge  AS thirdTENDAYS
from v9
where datepart(day,v9.trans_time_date) between 21 and 31  and
@Charge=v9.Charge

open CRS
FETCH NEXT FROM CRS
INTO @Charge
print  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
print @Charge 
FETCH NEXT FROM CRS
INTO @Charge

END
CLOSE CRS
DEALLOCATE CRS
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I am baffled by your query.  First, I don't understand why you want to use a cursor rather than just `select`ing the values.

But, your queries should not be returning anything.  Consider:

```
select 0.01*v9.charge  AS firstTENDAYS
from v9
where datepart(day, 9.trans_time_date) between 0 and 10 and
       @Charge = v9.charge;
```

`@Charge` is declared, but not given a value so it is `NULL`.  That should fail any comparisons.

Your three queries have no connection between them, so the cursor is only the first query. That may be related to the problem you see.

I suspect you want a simpler query such as:

```
select (case when day(v9.trans_time_date) <= 10 then 'firstTenDays'
             when day(v9.trans_time_date) <= 20 then 'secondTenDays'
             else 'thirdTenDays'
        end) as which,
       (case when day(v9.trans_time_date) <= 10 then 0.01 * v9.charge
             when day(v9.trans_time_date) <= 20 then 0.02 * v9.charge
             else 0.03 * v9.charge
        end) as chart
from v9;
```

Answer (score 0):

this absolutely shouldnt be done with cursor, but with a regular select.
however just to show you how a cursor should work i put it here:

```
Declare @firstTENDAYS table (charge decimal)
Declare @secondTENDAYS table (charge decimal)
Declare @thirdTENDAYS table (charge decimal)

Declare @Charge dec(10,2) =10
Declare CRS CURSOR FOR Select v9.charge, v9.trans_time_date From v9
Declare @v9_Charge numeric
Declare @v9_InsertDate smalldatetime


Open CRS
FETCH NEXT FROM CRS INTO @v9_Charge, @v9_InsertDate 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
 If @v9_Charge = @Charge
 Begin
        If @v9_InsertDate  between 0 and 10   
         Insert Into @firstTENDAYS SELECT 0.01*@v9_Charge  
        Else If  @v9_InsertDate  between 10 and 20   
         Insert Into @secondTENDAYS SELECT 0.02*@v9_Charge  
        Else If  @v9_InsertDate  between 21 and 31  
         Insert Into @thirdTENDAYS SELECT 0.03*@v9_Charge 
 End

FETCH NEXT FROM CRS INTO @v9_Charge, @v9_InsertDate 
END;
CLOSE CRS;
DEALLOCATE CRS;


select * from  @firstTENDAYS
select * from  @secondTENDAYS 
select * from  @thirdTENDAYS
```